# Possibility of throwing exactly one six

Tags: probability, probability-theory, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

I am reading the following question:

> What is the probability of throwing precisely one six when 6 dice are
> rolled?

So when we have one dice the probability of having one six is $\frac{1}6$
When we have six dice we can have 6 cases that the six can come i.e. first dice or second or third etc.
The total possible outcomes of throwing 6 dice is: $6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6\cdot6=6^6$
So the probability is: $\frac{6}{6^6}=\frac{1}{6^5}$

But the solution says:
The probability of throwing precicely $1$ six out of $6$ dices is:
$\binom{6}{1}\cdot\frac{1}6\cdot\frac{5}6\cdot\frac{5}6\cdot\frac{5}6\cdot\frac{5}6\cdot\frac{5}6\cdot\frac{5}6$

Could someone help me understand why is $\binom{6}{1}$ being used here? That equals to $6$ as I also reasoned but why would we use choice formula here? What does it mean?
Also I assume the $\frac{5}6$ is the probability of not throwing a $6$ but why does it have to be multiplied $6$ times.

If I apply this formula to the case of throwing $1$ six when we roll $2$ dice I get:
$\binom{2}{1}\cdot\frac{1}6\cdot\frac{5}6\cdot\frac{5}6 = 2\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{5^2}{6^2}=\frac{25}{108}$

But if I actually count the cases we have:

| Dice 1 | Dice 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 |
| 2 | 6 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 6 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 |
| 6 | 3 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 6 | 5 |

this is $\frac{10}{36}$.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because any one of the six dice could be the one which turns up with a six ... and in your example you have an extra factor $\frac 56$

Comment: @MathLover: I updated the post. Was an error.

Comment: @MarkBennet: What do you mean by "extra factor"? The solution mulitplies $\frac{5}{6}$ as many times as the number of dice and so do I here, there are $2$ dice.

Comment: You should have $\frac 16$ for the one which scores a $6$ and $\frac 56$ for each one that doesn't. In your example you specify two dice, so just one factor $\frac 56$. If you don't understand that part, then that is the place where your confusion lies.

Comment: If you roll two dice, there are two ways of getting exactly one 6, a 6 on the first roll or a 6 on the second roll, which occurs with probability $$\frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{5}{6} + \frac{5}{6} \cdot \frac{1}{6} = \binom{2}{1}\left(\frac{1}{6}\right)\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)$$

Comment: @MarkBennet: Why in the solution example then it multiplies $\frac{5}6$ six times though? I dont get the difference

Comment: @N.F.Taussig: The way you phrased it helps me. But I don't get why we multiply more times the $\frac{5}6$ in the example solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding what @N.F.Taussig said  in the comments of the question.

Instead of thinking about $6$ dice think about one single dice rolled six times. In six rolls you want to have one exaclty $6$ and all the other results must be different.

You can get a $6$ on the first throw with probability $\frac{1}{6}$ and then the probability that in the next $5$ rolls you do not get a $6$ is $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5$

On the opposite hand, at the first throw you can get a number different from $6$ with probability $5/6$ and get a $6$ at the second throw. Then all the other 4 throws must end up with a number different from a $6$. This gives you again $\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5$

Go on and count the probability you can get the $6$ at the $i$-th throw for $i = 3,4,5,6$.

This lead you to the result that the probability of getting exactly one $6$ in $6$ different rolls is
$$\binom{6}{1}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^5$$

---

If the book gives $\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^6$ then it is an error.

Comment: Yes the solution says $(\frac{5}{6})^6$. So that is a typo then?

Comment: Yes, it is. (I need to add some extra characters to add this comment)

Comment: I have one last question. Why is the notation $\binom{6}{1}$ being used? I mean $\binom{n}{k}$ means select k from n without caring about the order so how this definition fits here confuses me. I mean couldn't we just multiply by the number of dice? What does using the binomial choice have to do here?

Comment: Instead of giving you the exact answer I leave you an exercise: What is the probability of throwing precisely $k$ six when $n$ dices are rolled? Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: I think I got it. So it is a way to generalize to an arbitrary number.